# Creating neon vector design aesthetic used in Apple's 2019 WWDC graphics in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, svg, shadows, blur

Apple has some pretty cool designs for their [2019 WWDC](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc19/):

[image]
[image]

I would like to learn how to create (and create) vector images / icons like this in Illustrator. What is the name for this type of design? Are there resources you would recommend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Illustrator, using two paths over a dark blue background:

[image: Outline view]

Working on the Appearance Panel, adding strokes with different weights, blend modes, opacities, and for the back strokes, Feather effects and Transform to move them down-left:

[image: Ray]

[image: Process]